# Rails is not processing my jQuery .click events (can't even get an alert to pop up.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

My rails 4 app isn't processing jQuery .click events at all.

From the Chrome browser console it works when I type this then click a h3.

```
$("h3").click(function() { return alert("Clicked that thang");});   // This alerts on click of a h3
```

But when I include the equivilent code (in CoffeeScript) in my app it does nothing..

```
# app/assets/javascripts/collaborators.js.coffee

alert("does this work?")        // yes this pops up an alert

$("h3").click ->
  alert("Does this work?")      // sadly nothing now happens when I click my h3's
```

I can tell that jQuery is loaded.

Chrome console:

```
>> $.fn.jquery
"1.10.2"
```

I also had a go at clearing the asset pipeline:

$> rake asset clean    # but that didn't help me either.

Help, what's up, what am I missing?

Rails 4.0 app.

Comment: look at event delegation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: `$(document).on 'click', 'h3' ->
  alert("Does this work?") `

Comment: try binding the event with body tag.

Comment: @ArunPJohny you missed a comma after your h3 but yeah this worked!! $(document).on 'click', 'h3', -> alert("Does this work?")

Comment: but why? (Ps add yours as an answer so its votable/comment able.

Comment: Thanks everyone I've got a few answers that work now, and I think you're all saying it's because my h3 wasn't loaded yet when my js ran. But which is the best approach. Let me know why your approach is better/when I should be using it or not.

Comment: Wow that's the best response I've ever had, like 6 of you in under 10 mins. I love StackOverflow. Thanks so much all. I'm accepting @ArunPJohny cause he was first in with a working answer but I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are dealing with dynamically created elements. The solution for that is to use event delegation

```
$(document).on 'click', 'h3', ->
  alert("Does this work?")
```

To read more about why
- [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)
- [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Is it just as well I use $(body).on here or is $(document).on better for any reason?

Comment: @Evolve both are the same... but if you have a more specific ancestor for all the target `h3` element then use that... like a static `div#heparent` which will have all the `h3` elements then you can use `('#h3parent').on...`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("body").on "click", "h3", ()->
  alert("Does this work?")
```

If this is not the case, then `turbolinks` might be the culprit, do this

```
ready = ()->
  $("body").on "click", "h3", ()->
    alert("Does this work?")

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately this didn't work either for me.

Comment: I have code that uses this exact structure in my application.js, in the js for this controller, eg collaborators.js.coffee are you suggesting I include the full code as above or can I just extend to get into the existing ready method that is being run?

Answer (score 1):

It works successfully from console because your html code is present and so it can find h3 element and registers click event in DOM whereas, this might not be the case with coffee script. JS completes execution before HTML elements are loaded. so Try using document.ready as below or alternatively you can also use event delegation.

```
$(document).ready ->
 $("h3").click ->
  alert("Does this work?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your element is not loaded when your JS gets executed, so it cannot find any h3 element. You have to [wait until your document is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$ ->
  $("h3").click ->
    alert("Does this work?")
```